# Animation of UICollectionView height looks strange, cells zoom out

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to show a UICollectionView in a UITableViewCell. Initially the CollectionView shouldn't be shown, but when the users presses a button the CollectionView should become visible with an animation. I got this working however the first time the CollectionView becomes visible it looks like the cells get zoomed out, if I hide the CollectionView and expand it again, the animation looks correct:

http://g.recordit.co/DBhZCmJKPj.gif

This is the code for animation the change:

```swift
func expand() {
    tableView?.beginUpdates()
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
        self.imageViewDisclosureIndicator.setImage(UIImage(named: "arrow-up"), for: .normal)
        self.collectionViewHeight.constant = self.collectionView.intrinsicContentSize.height
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.isExpanded = true
    }, completion: nil)
    tableView?.endUpdates()
}

func collapse() {
    tableView?.beginUpdates()
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
        self.imageViewDisclosureIndicator.setImage(UIImage(named: "arrow-down"), for: .normal)
        self.collectionViewHeight.constant = CGFloat(0.0)
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.isExpanded = false
    }, completion: nil)
    tableView?.endUpdates()
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `self.layoutIfNeeded` outside the animation.

Based off your code, I don't see why you need that line of code, but it is probably the cause for your problem. I think that the content would even load fine without that line, because the size of the content view of the collection view is independent of the height of the collection view.

Comment: I agree, that line could be removed. However when I remove it the animation stays the same.